# Prove that $0.\overline{9}= 1$

Tags: calculus, decimal-expansion

We all know that $\frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline{3}$, and that when we multiply it by $3$, we get $1$. But, $3\times \frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline{9}$.

Are there any ideas on how to prove that $0.\overline{9}= 1$? 
I have no ideas, I only wrote down that $0.\overline{9}+x= 1$ for $x\neq 0$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: 1.0000.... and 0.99999...(infinitely many) are equivalent representation of the same real number

Comment: $1$ is $0.999$ are distinct. They differ by $0.0001$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical proof:

Let $x=0.999...$ Then $$10x=9.999...\implies 10x-x=9.999...-0.999...$$ so $$9x=9\implies x=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$0,999...=9\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^n}=9\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}-1\right)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

From
$$
x=0.\overline{9}
$$ one has
$$
10x=9+x,\qquad 9x=9, 
$$that is
$$
x=0.\overline{9}=\frac{9}{9}=1.
$$